# Trying to switch from Cinnamon to MATE on Linux Mint, but nothing happens when I click on the session icon

Tags: linux-mint, login

I have Linux Mint 17.3 which was originally installed with the Cinnamon desktop. I am wanting to install MATE and switch to that instead, and used [a guide](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-install-mate-in-linux-mint-cinnamon-edition/) to do so. The last step is to "click on the lambda" button in the upper-right corner of the login screen, which then pops up with a selector:

[image: Linux Mint Select a session]

However, this doesn't work for me. Instead of a lambda, I see the letters "ci". When I click on it, nothing happens. I can log in, click on the power icon in the upper left, and navigate through the slideshow, but not this. Here is what I see:

[image: Linux Mint Login Screen]

I know that I have MATE properly installed because when I run `apt-get install mint-meta-mate` from the command line, I am told that I already have the latest version.

How can I get the login screen session icon to work so that I can switch to MATE? If I can't do anything, is there an alternate way to switch?

**Edit:** I turned off the login window preference to always choose the last user, and that changed the `ci` icon into a gear. Still can't click on it though.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=192311), the default login window theme does not support changing desktop environments. Switching from the Mint-X theme to Linux Mint GDM should resolve the issue.

The theme can be changed at:

`Menu -> Administration -> Login Window -> Theme`